# Profiling App Startup Time in Android Apps

Tags: android, profiling, trace, perfetto

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#app-startup-perfetto

I am trying to profile my app startup time.

It tells me "In Perfetto, find the row with the Android App Startups derived metric."
[image: Perfetto example]

Only problem is:
There is NO row with the Android App Startups derived metric.
[image: My perfetto trace]

It says "If you don't see it, try capturing a trace using the on-device system tracing app."

I DID capture the trace using the on-device system tracing app.
What might be missing from the instructions are some sort of settings I need to use to make it appear.
Or was my app startup so stealthy that it wasn't detected? I'm trying to trace the application startup before adding an appwidget.

Answer (score 0):

1st. kill the app you want to trace

2. run trace cmd

3.stop the cmd ,or use -t parameter (-t N            trace for N seconds [default 5])
make sure N is longer than time of startup.

here is my my command
atrace -b 10000 -z gfx input view wm am res sched freq idle mmc binder_driver binder_lock dalvik ss -t 20 > /data/local/tmp/some.trace